# java on the command line

Tags: java, command-line, package

I am having some problems trying to run my program on the command line. I have created 2 directories in my NetBeansProjects directory. The first one is called foodpackage and the second one is a subdirectory of foodpackage which is called fruitpackage. Inside the fruitpackage I have two java files called Food.java and FoodMain.java. The code in **Food.java** is as shown:

```
package foodpackage.fruitpackage;

public class Food{

// declare instance variabels
private String foodVarieties;
private String foodList;

// returns foodVarieties
public String getFoodVarieties(){
return foodVarieties;
}

// sets foodVarieties
public void setFoodVarieties(String temp){
foodVarieties = temp;
}

// returns foodList
public String getFoodList(){
return foodList;
}

// sets foodList
public void setFoodList(String temp){
foodList = temp;
}
}
```

The code for **FoodMain.java** is as shown:

```
import foodpackage.fruitpackage.*;

public class FoodMain{

public static void main(String args[]){

// create an object instance of Food class
Food t = new Food();

// set the foodVarieties
t.setFoodVarieties("Food varieties: Vegetables and Meat");

// set the foodList
t.setFoodList("Food list: chicken, lettuce, and broccoli");

// print the foodVarieties
System.out.println(t.getFoodVarieties());

// print the foodList
System.out.println(t.getFoodList());
}
}
```

I ran it on the command line as shown below:

```
cd /Users/timothylee/NetBeansProjects
javac -cp . foodpackage/fruitpackage/*.java
java -classpath . foodpackage/fruitpackage.FoodMain
```

When I ran this, I got the error of

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: foodpackage/fruitpackage/FoodMain (wrong name: FoodMain)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

May anyone help me to fix this error? Thank you.

Comment: You're using `System.out.println("some string" = aVariable);`, probably you meant to use `+` instead of `=`. Yes, this surely was a typo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `+` instead of `=` to concatenate `Strings`

```
System.out.println("ID: " + annaID.getStudentID());
```

Answer (score 1):

Your line is currently:

```
System.out.println("ID: " = annaID.getStudentID());
```

`=` is not the operator you're looking for.

```
System.out.println("ID: " + annaID.getStudentID());
```

This will concatenate the String with the integer returned by `annaID.getStudentID()`

Answer (score 0):

When you do this:

```
System.out.println("ID: " = annaID.getStudentID());
```

You are trying to assign a `int` to a string, which is bad.  Use the `+` operator instead:

```
System.out.println("ID: " + annaID.getStudentID());
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your code... by the image you've provided it looks like you've typed "=" instead of "+" in system.out.println statement